# Same function name, different C files

Tags: c

I have two tools in C to parse data from a database to an XML file or a normal text file. Both files contain the same function names but with different implementations, so I am working on merging them both in a single tool and the output type (XML or text) will depend on the input from the user.

So, the problem is having same function (and struct) names but with different implementations. How can I overcome this situation without having to rename everything because that will lead to a mess.

Thank you.

Comment: *with [namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace), that's basically what they were invented for* - edit: nevermind, that's c++

Comment: If these functions are only called locally in the same translation unit, you can make them `static`. Otherwise - only rename.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in C. It's possible with namespace in C++

Comment: @StefanRiedel There are no namespaces in C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh right, my bad.

Comment: Why merge them?  Keep the tools separate, and write a wrapper that can invoke the appropriate tool.  "Integration bad, modularity good"

Comment: You implement a "poor mans namespace" in c by using prefixes

Comment: Make them static and have a struct with function pointers exported from each file.

Comment: If the functions are used only among the sources of the separate tools and are never used in common code, then one option may be to compile all the objects for one tool, link them together into a new relocatable object in which the names of those functions have been omitted (all references to the functions are resolved during the link), and then do the same with the objects of the other tool. This will produce two objects that can be linked together with no conflicts.

Comment: E.g., with Apple’s `ld`, `-r` produces a relocatable file, and `-unexported_symbol <symbol>` and `-unexported_symbols_list <file>` can be used to suppress export of function names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use both sets of types and functions in the same program at the same time, and if those type and function names have to be visible outside of their enclosing source file(s)<sup>1</sup> (i.e., you have a `.h` file with those type definitions and function declarations), then you *must* rename at least one set of them.  No other choice. C doesn't provide *user-definable* namespaces<sup>2</sup>, so anything with external linkage *must* have a globally unique name.

If those type and function names *don't* have to be visible outside of their source file<sup>3</sup> (i.e., they don't have to be called by a function defined outside of their source file), then you can declare the functions as `static` - that will limit their visibility to the enclosing source file.  If the type names are local to the source file (you haven't put them in a `.h` that must be included by another source file), then they won't be exported.

If you only need to use one set or the other, but which set isn't known until runtime, you can put each in a shared library and then load the correct one at runtime (using `dlopen` on the *nix side - not sure what the Windows equivalent would be).

A fourth option would be to switch to C++ and wrap each set in a unique namespace; depending on what you're doing that may be the fastest option.

---

1. The function names have what is known as *external linkage*.

   C has four namespaces - label names, tag names, `struct` and `union` member names, and *all other identifiers* (variable names, function names, typedef names, enumeration constants, etc.).  Those namespaces are fixed, and you can't create any more.

   The function names have either *internal* or no linkage.

Answer (score -5):

You can enclose each of the function definitions in a different namespace.  You won't have to change intra-namespace function calls, but you will have to preface inter-namespace function calls with the "other" namespace.

Comment: There are no namespaces in C

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That is going to come as a surprise to the authors of C 2018 6.2.3 1: “… Thus there are separate *name spaces*…”

Comment: @EricPostpischil You know exactly what I meant.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I did, but students do not learn from words that are incorrect. In order to know the correct meaning of such a sentence, you have to already know the correct meaning of the sentence. It is simple enough to say, correctly, that C does not have separate name spaces for function names.